# Python __getitem__ performance between lists and dicts

Tags: python, arrays, performance, hashmap, dynamic-programming

I've implemented a dynamic programming algorithm (bottom-up).
As a quick fix I've used dictionaries instead of fixed sized arrays for the DP table, but given my input size (*n* up to 50k, *m* up to 100), I think there's quite a bit to gain by refactoring `dp_table: Dict[int, Dict[int, float]]` to `dp_table: List[List[float]]`.

We know that hash tables have O(1) running time for indexing, but with a 'high' constant value, whereas list indexing is O(1) with a supposedly much smaller constant.

What is the performance difference between `dict.__getitem__` and `list.__getitem__`?
Is there even more to gain by using numpy arrays?

Comment: The performance difference would be the change in the constant. Have you tried running any benchmarks yourself?

Comment: I'd expect performance benchmarks for such ubiquitous operations to exist already, yet I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward to benchmark using `timeit`.

```
>>> timeit.Timer('values[50]', 'values = {i: i for i in range(100)}').timeit(number = 10**7)
0.3076519769999999
>>> timeit.Timer('values[50]', 'values = list(range(100))').timeit(number = 10**7)
0.2913365720000005
>>> timeit.Timer('values[50]', 'import numpy; values = numpy.arange(100)').timeit(number = 10**7)
1.262765399000001
```

Oddly enough, numpy arrays perform terrible here.

Answer (score -1):

*What is the performance difference between `dict.__getitem__` and `list.__getitem__`?*

[wiki.python article TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) claim following time-complexity:

- for `list` Get Item: average case O(1) amortized worst case O(1)
- for `dict` Get Item: average case O(1) amortized worst case O(n)

Keep in mind that these are values for CPython and other python implementations might differ.